# Extract Data between two HTML tags with PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, explode, preg-match-all

I already have this code, but how can I prevent it from returning data if the $start or $end is not found?

```
function get_data($start,$end,$data){
$r = explode($start, $data);
if (isset($r[1])){
    $r = explode($end, $r[1]);
    return $r[0];
}}//end get_data
```

Comment: They will both exist inside the function, so you have to test for emptiness.

Comment: if (empty($start) || empty($end)) return false;

Comment: Clarifying question... by "`$end` does not exist", do you mean within `$data`? (That's how I read it, but the comments/answer show that I am alone in that thought. ^^)

Comment: @user1282355  Your question appears unresolved.  It also doesn't look very refined.  Can you provide some sample input (values for `$start`, `$end`, and `$data`)?  I would like to help you find a resolution.  Of course, if you are no longer interested in an answer, please delete your question so that SO users don't waste time trying to solve it.